# attaching an image (or object) from memory to an email in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, email-attachments

I have an image in memory that I've created (using numpy and PIL), and I'd like to attach it to a created email programatically. I know I could save it to the filesystem, and then reload/attach it, but it seems in-efficient: is there a way to just pipe it to the mime attachment without saving?

The save/reload version:

```
from PIL import Image
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

...some img creation steps...

msg = MIMEMultipart()
img_fname = '/tmp/temp_image.jpg'
img.save( img_fname)
with open( img_fname, 'rb') as fp:
    img_file = MIMEImage( fp.read() )
    img_file.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=img_fname )
    msg.attach( img_file)

...add other attachments and main body of email text...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting PIL image to MIMEImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547625/converting-pil-image-to-mimeimage)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`MIMEImage` says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.image.MIMEImage) that the first argument is just "a string containing the raw image data", so you don't have to `open()` then `.read()` it from a file.

If you're making it in PIL and there isn't a way to serialize it directly (there might not be, I can't recall), you can use a [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) (or `BytesIO`...whichever works with what `MIMEImage` really wants) file-like buffer to save the file, then read it out as a string. [Related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646286/python-pil-how-to-write-png-image-to-string) Modernized adapted excerpt:

```
import io
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

# ... make some image

outbuf = io.StringIO()
image.save(outbuf, format="PNG")
my_mime_image = MIMEImage(outbuf.getvalue())
outbuf.close()
```